# Knowledge Article Title Header shown only for the versions in the user's language

Tags: community, knowledge, community-builder, napili, articles

I have enabled knowledge base for the communities. The template community that I am using, is Napilii template. I am configuring the layout of the article detail page where the core component, is the native Article Content Component. I have configured the parameters of this component, as follows:

- Record ID: {!recordId}
- Url Name: {!urlName}

What I am finding strange is that when access the article in the current user's language version, I can see the Header, where there is the Title and underneath of that, the published date and the type of the article.
[image]

When I access the versions in italian and german of the same article, I get the respective views:

Italian:
[image]

German:
[image]

I have done another test, where I have changed the user's default language in Italian, and in that case there I get to see the article Header, only for italian version.

My question, is if there is any workaround to this issue here. Maybe some parameter to configure to the Article Content Standard component, from the builder.

Thanks in advance,
E.

Comment: Couple things 1) Can you confirm the languages you've added to the Community are active? Setup > Knowledge Settings > Edit > Multiple Languages and 2) That you have Translated the Standard Articles and have created or imported them with the Italian and German language code.